# Access member of a JSON string array

Tags: arrays, json

I have the following JSON string and for example I need to access a single element of the array. Let's say I just wanted to pull out "host2." I keep trying things like `members[1]` but that doesn't work. I keep getting "undefined."

```
{
  "members": [
    "host1",
    "host2",
    "host3"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to pull out the value of this key?Try members.hosts2 in this case.

Comment: In what *language*? C#? Java? JavaScript? VB.Net?

Comment: If JavaScript, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: Yes, exactly and what's the system that is trying to access that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Example

```
 let d = {
  "members": [
    "host1",
    "host2",
    "host3"
  ]
};
console.log(d);
console.log(d.members[1]);
```

[image]